# Having trouble creating a debian debug package

Tags: debugging, debian, dpkg, debian-packaging

We have a fairly large project that consists of files in multiple git repositories that is built for multiple platforms. For each platform and repo, a build is run, and the output goes into a common directory. The directory layout (greatly simplified) is something like this:

```
multi:
build/  part1/  part2/  Makefile  VERSION

build:

multi/part1:
Makefile  part1.c

multi/part2:
Makefile  part2.c
```

Until fairly recently, we built the project for rpm-based systems. A customer needed for a Debian system. So we did some research. We created a `build-deb.sh` script in the `multi` directory, and created a `debian` directory under `multi` which contains the `control`, `conffile`, `preinst`, `postinst`, `prerm`, `postrm`.

**make-deb.sh:**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

. build/buildrc

version="${MULTI_MAJOR}.${MULTI_MINOR}.${MULTI_REVISION}.${MULTI_BUILD}"
branch="$MULTI_BRANCH"

# Set up the name and directories
package="Multi-$branch-$version.debian11.x86_64"
multi="build/${package}"
debdir="$multi/DEBIAN"

# Create the directories
rm -rf $multi
mkdir -p $debdir
mkdir -p $multi/usr/local/multi/bin

cp build/part1/* build/part2/* $multi/usr/local/multi/bin

# Copy dpkg files
cp debian/* $debdir

# Update the control file
size=`du -sk --exclude=DEBIAN $multi | cut -f1`
sed -i -r  -e "s/@size/$size/" -e "s/@version/$version/" $debdir/control

# Build the package
cd build
dpkg-deb --build ${package}
```

**debian/control:**

```
Package: Multi
Version: @version
Priority: optional
Architecture: amd64
Installed-Size: @size
Maintainer: <devs@domain.org>
Description: Multi-part System
 This is a simple Multi-part system that includes two executables,
 copied in from different directories.
```

The script creates a `multi/build/multi-main-3.5.3.9999-debian11-x86_64` directory, and copies in appropriate files from the `build` directory and the `debian` directory.

We get the following output when we run the build:

```
$ make PLATFORM=debian
make[1]: Entering directory '/srv/devel/multi/part1'
mkdir -p ../build/part1
gcc -g -O2 -o ../build/part1/part1 part1.c
make[1]: Leaving directory '/srv/devel/multi/part1'
make[1]: Entering directory '/srv/devel/multi/part2'
mkdir -p ../build/part2
gcc -g -O2 -o ../build/part2/part2 part2.c
make[1]: Leaving directory '/srv/devel/multi/part2'
dpkg-deb: building package 'multi' in 'Multi-main-3.5.3.43.debian11.x86_64.deb'.
```

After doing a build, the `build` directory looks like this:

```
build/:
Multi-main-3.5.3.43.debian11.x86_64/
part1/
part2/
Multi-main-3.5.3.43.debian11.x86_64.deb
buildrc

build/Multi-main-3.5.3.43.debian11.x86_64:
debian/
usr/

build/Multi-main-3.5.3.43.debian11.x86_64/DEBIAN:
control

build/Multi-main-3.5.3.43.debian11.x86_64/usr:
local/

build/Multi-main-3.5.3.43.debian11.x86_64/usr/local:
multi/

build/Multi-main-3.5.3.43.debian11.x86_64/usr/local/multi:
bin/

build/Multi-main-3.5.3.43.debian11.x86_64/usr/local/multi/bin:
part1*
part2*

build/part1:
part1*

build/part2:
part2*
```

Ok, might be a bit cludgy, but it produces a `.deb` file that can be installed.

So, *now* we need to build a debug package. After doing some more research, it looked like all we had to do was add a `Package: Multi-dbg` section to the `debian/control` file and run `dh_strip --dbg-package=Multi-dbg`. Well that just gave us an error `several package info entries found, only one allowed`. Ok, take that section out, and run `dh_strip --dbg-package=Multi`. **That** gave us the error `dh_strip: error: "debian/control" not found. Are you sure you are in the correct directory?`.

Hmm, cd into the `build/Multi-main-3.5.3.43.debian11.x86_64` directory and try `dh_strip` again. Error: `"debian/control" not found. Are you sure you are in the correct directory?`. Ok, rename the `build/Multi-main-3.5.3.43.debian11.x86_64/DEBIAN` directory as `build/Multi-main-3.5.3.43.debian11.x86_64/debian` and try again. Made a little progress:

```
$ make PLATFORM=debian
dpkg-deb: building package 'multi' in 'Multi-main-3.5.3.43.debian11.x86_64.deb'.
dh_strip: error: could not find Source: line in control file.
make: *** [Makefile:31: dist] Error 255
```

So we just need to add a `Source:` line in the control file. According to research, it's supposed to be the name of a source package. We don't have a source package, so maybe just make one up? Tried `Source: Multi` and `Source: Multi.deb` and `Source: Multi-src.deb` and other combinations and always end up with

```
$ make PLATFORM=debian
dpkg-deb: building package 'multi' in 'Multi-main-3.5.3.43.debian11.x86_64.deb'.
dh_strip: error: Source-field must be a valid package name, got: "Multi-src.deb", should match "(?^:^(?^:[a-z0-9][-+\.a-z0-9]+)$)"
make: *** [Makefile:31: dist] Error 255
```

Also tried all lower-case variants and got `dh_strip: warning: No packages to build. Possible architecture mismatch: amd64, want:`

It must be fairly simple, lots of people do it. I just can't figure out how to get the debug package. A little help here??

Comment: `dpkg-deb --build` is very low-level.  I find it much easier to use the high-level `debhelper` tools.  Building the symbols package is then a simple matter of specifying the package in `debian/control` and adding a `override_dh_strip` target in `debian/rules`.